# Problems rotating tiff image

Tags: java, applet, rotation, tiff, affinetransform

I have found a code to rotate a **tiff image** clockwise but its taking so much time and even scrolling the image in jscrollpanel is also very slow.

1.So is there any easy method to rotate a tiff image or

2.Any tweaking is needed in the below code to rotate it quickly.

```
            ReadableByteChannel rBytChnl = Channels.newChannel(url);
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(4096 * 1024);
        rBytChnl.read(buffer);
        byte[] data = buffer.array();
        SeekableStream stream = new ByteArraySeekableStream(data);
        ParameterBlock pb = new ParameterBlock();
        pb.add(stream);
        RenderedOp op = JAI.create("tiff", pb);
        TransposeType type = TransposeDescriptor.ROTATE_90;
        ParameterBlock pb1 = new ParameterBlock();
        pb1.addSource(op);
        pb1.add(type);
        pb1.add(new InterpolationBilinear());
        image = JAI.create("transpose", pb1, null);
```

Comment: i'd render the image into a BufferedImage, and then rotate that.

Comment: I did the same but the pixels has got increased and a part of the image is truncated.I need an image without any change in pixels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have adjusted the affine transform to meet my needs and its working fine. This is only for 90 degree clockwise rotation and for other needs change the code accordingly.

```
       PlanarImage pi = PlanarImage.wrapRenderedImage(image);
        BufferedImage bi = pi.getAsBufferedImage();
        AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
            at.translate(-(image.getWidth() - image.getHeight()) / 2, (image.getWidth() - image.getHeight()) / 2);
            at.rotate(Math.toRadians(90),bi.getWidth()/2,bi.getHeight() / 2);
        AffineTransformOp opRotated = new AffineTransformOp(at,
                AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR);
        image = opRotated.filter(bi, null);
```